# why is window.open php fetching variable is fetching same id every time and not the remaining entries?

Tags: javascript, php

Here in the code, $fetch['id'] working fine else where but in window.open it is taking same value always that is id number 25, and not the other ids, i can't understand why is it so....Please help........

```
$i=1;
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($data_qry))
{
    echo $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."/edit_user_comment.php?id=".$fetch['id']; // here variable working fine....
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['comp_name']."</td>";
    if (strlen($fetch['comp_add'])> 10)
    {
        echo "<td>".substr($fetch['comp_add'], 0, 10)."...";
    }else{
        echo "<td>".$fetch['comp_add'];
        }"</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['business_registration_no']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['email_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['tel_no']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['fax']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['prsn_in_chrg']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['ph_no']."</td>";
    ?>
    <script>
    function windowopen(){
                window.open('<?= $url; ?>','Comment Edit', 'menubar=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=yes,width=500, height=500');
                //here it is takin $fetch['id']=25 only and not other ids, i want to know the mistake i m doing here... Please help
            }
    </script>
    <?php       
    if($fetch['comments']!='')
    {
        echo "<td><textarea name='comments' id='id_comments'>".$fetch['comments']."</textarea>
    <a onclick='return windowopen();' class='button button-primary button-large edit'>Edit</a></td>";
    }else{ 
        echo "<td><a onclick='return windowopen();' class='button button-primary button-large'>Add Comment</a></td>";
    }       
    echo "<td> <a href='response.php?id=".$fetch['id']."&action=approve' class='button button-primary button-large approve'>Approve</a> <a href='response.php?id=".$fetch['id']."&action=dissapprove' class='button button-primary button-large'>Dissapprove</a> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";       
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: Declare your `windowopen` function once, outside of the while loop and then call the function with the URL passed as a parameter when a link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my earlier comment - Generated links should look something like:

```
echo '<td><a onclick="return windowopen(\''.$url.'\');">Add Comment</a></td>';
```

...and your function should be declared once outside of the loop like :

```
<script>
function windowopen(url)
{
      window.open(url,'Comment Edit', '/*blah*/');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are redeclaring the same function `windowopen()` so the last declaration overrides the others and you got the same function for all elements